# OpenGL: Turn off multiple texture units

Tags: opengl, textures, multitexturing

How to turn off multiple texture units because they influence to other render parts.
I activate my them:

```
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + index);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
               ((MaterialSampler2D)specular).texture.getTOB());
        shader.setTexture2(index);
```

Is there something like glDeactivateTexture?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`glActiveTexture` does not activate texture-units. It merely selects which texture-unit you're currently modifying (yes, OpenGL's object state managing is horrible).
You activate textures with `glEnable(<texture-target>)` and `glDisable(<texture-target>)`. In your case, the target would be `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

So to answer your question: Select the texture-unit `i` by using `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+i)` and then disable it with `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.

Note that all this is redundant with shaders - you can just not access the values there.

Comment: I use shader and I don`t need to use glEnable/glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D), do I? And I use this, it does not help me.

Comment: Exactly, except for some dodgy drivers that are buggy (and I think there was a bug that affected this issue on ATI drivers at one time)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like glDisable? http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml

Comment: What argument value do you think help me?

Comment: from the top of my head something like

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

Not sure if this is what you intend to do?